# Создаем таблицу с Cross Join

Tags: sql, mysql

Как сделать такую таблицу?

```
id | den | time|  workman
---+-----+-----+----------
 1 |  Пн |08.00| ANN
 2 |  Пн |09.00| LEO
 3 |  Пн |10.00| VALMONDT
...
 9 |  Пн |18.00| JULIO
10 |  Вт |08.00| GEORGE
11 |  Вт |09.00| BARAK
...
 ? |  Вт |18.00| RUZVELT
...
 ? |  Сб |17.00| ANN
 ? |  Сб |18.00| BEN
```

6 дней в неделю с `08.00` до `18.00` кто-то должен выйти на работу. Не могу сообразить как составить таблицу с полями `den x time`. По сути это `Cross Join`, но у меня получилось слишком много временных таблиц. Кто-нибудь знает более простой способ?

Comment: Откуда данные (`workman`) брать?

Comment: Это для наглядности :)) Мне первые 3 столбца важнее.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select * from 
(select 'пн' den 
union all
select 'вт' den 
...
) x
cross join
(select '8.00' time
union all
select '9.00' time
...
) y
```

Если MySQL поддерживает конструктор таблиц, то можно написать короче:

```
select * from
(values ('пн'),('вт')) as x (den)
cross join
(values ('8.00'), ('9.00')) y (time)
```

Comment: Для полноты:

    select
      x.n * 11 + y.n - 1 as id,
      x.den,
      y.time
    from 
      (
        select 1 n, 'пн' den 
        union all
        select 2, 'вт' den 
        ...
      ) x,
      (
        select 1 n, '8.00' time
        union all
        select 2, '9.00' time
        ...
      ) y

Comment: Для пополнения полноты:-)

create table foo as
select
  x.n * 11 + y.n - 1 as id,
  x.den,
  y.time
from 
  (
    select 1 n, 'пн' den 
    union all
    select 2, 'вт' den 
    ...
  ) x,
  (
    select 1 n, '8.00' time
    union all
    select 2, '9.00' time
    ...
  ) y